# SQL: can't understand CASE syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to solve a Hackerrank problem of detecting the triangle type for which I have the following code:

```
SELECT A,B,C FROM TRIANGLES
    CASE
        WHEN (A >= B + C) OR (B >= A + C) OR (C >= A + B) THEN "Not A Triangle"
        WHEN A = B AND B = C THEN "Equilateral"
        WHEN (A = B AND B = C) OR (B = C AND C = A) OR (C = A AND A = B) THEN "Isosceles"
        ELSE "Scalene"
    END;
```

But it does not work:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE
        WHEN (A >= B + C) OR (B >= A + C) OR (C >= A + B) THEN "Not A Trian' at line 2
```

Comment: You're using `CASE` incorrectly. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Case must be part of select or where clause

Comment: that's not that it can't understand the syntax, is that you are using it wrong. You can't just add that `CASE` expression after the `FROM`

Comment: Double quotes are for identifiers, e.g. column names. Use single quotes for string literals. E.g. `'Not a square'`.

Comment: Also, I would say that if it's a Hackerrank problem and you can't solve it, maybe honesty is the best policy here.

Comment: The case statement should be moved between `C` and `FROM`.

Comment: Well, I read the syntax and samples. My code is very similar, but does not work. I'm trying to detect the triangle type.

Comment: Adrian Wragg it's a public task: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/what-type-of-triangle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you want your output like this:

```
A    B    C   TYPE
6    2    3   Not a Triangle
3    3    3   Equilater
```

and so on...

Try this:

```
SELECT A,B,C, 
CASE
    WHEN (A >= B + C) OR (B >= A + C) OR (C >= A + B) THEN "Not A Triangle"
    WHEN A = B AND B = C THEN "Equilateral"
    WHEN (A = B AND B = C) OR (B = C AND C = A) OR (C = A AND A = B) THEN "Isosceles"
    ELSE "Scalene"
END AS type
FROM TRIANGLES
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you intended to do, but this should work :

```
SELECT A,B,C ,
       CASE
           WHEN (A >= B + C) OR (B >= A + C) OR (C >= A + B) THEN 'Not A Triangle'
           WHEN A = B AND B = C THEN 'Equilateral'
           WHEN (A = B AND B = C) OR (B = C AND C = A) OR (C = A AND A = B) THEN 'Isosceles'
           ELSE 'Scalene'
       END
FROM TRIANGLES
```

You had two mistakes, first, strings need to be wrapped with single quotes, double quotes are for column names. Second, Syntax is:

```
SELECT <columns>
FROM <Table>
WHERE <Filters>
```

Comment: Just a point of clarification - single quotes are the SQL standard for delimiting strings, but MySQL does support double quotes. For column & table names it is the backtick NOT a single quote that should be used.